# Is possible to save recorder audio file in musics in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudiorecorder

Hi in my app I have one feature to record audio and save it application directory. Client asking me is it possible to save audio file in musics?. That is client need to play recorded audio file without our application. I searched lot but cant find solution

Answer (score 1):

No all iOS applications are sandboxed and the app data generated by the app cannot be used by other apps and can't to saved into other apps. The only way to share data between apps is through `UIActivityViewController` and it unfortunately does not provide any way of opening a file in `music` app. It is possible for `jailbroken` devices however.